# Website left aligned on iPad

Tags: html, css, ipad, margin

I'm having problems with `margin: 0 auto` with my iPad. The `div` aligns to the left, not the center like it does on my desktop.

You can view the site here: [www.amplify.io](http://www.amplify.io)

The container has a width and I've tried a few solutions on the web but to no avail... any pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the width you are setting?

Comment: You should really fix all these [HTML validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=www.amplify.io&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), especially the ones that flag a bunch of duplicate ID's.... very bad.

Comment: That's why it's posted as a comment... just trying to help you improve your HTML skills.  You'll surely create more problems when you duplicate your ID's.

Comment: Ok fair enough, but the site is not finished, I am planning to fix these errors once I sort out this iPad nonsense!

Comment: Cart -> Horse.  I hope your HTML errors are not the root cause of your iPad nonsense.

Comment: they weren't - thanks for your help any way.

Comment: this solution will also solve zoom in issues on smart phone. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272420/webpage-starts-zoomed-in-on-mobile-devices

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Might be a case of overflow happening because you don't set a viewport for mobile devices.

Try adding:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
                           maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

to your HTML head to be certain.  Which should set the page width to the iPad's width and make sure no scaling is happening.

Comment: Yes, this has helped. I also had to put some of the content within a wider div as some of it overflowed like you suggested. I tried fixing validation as others suggested that wasn't the problem!

Answer (score 0):

[Validator Results](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=www.amplify.io&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

You've got 26 errors and 11 warnings on your website.  I would bet money that the reason your website isn't aligning correctly is due to one of these things.  Fix your errors and see if that fixes the problem, otherwise, readdress the situation.

Comment: I agree (see my comment on the OP).  Lots of duplicate ID's too.  However, there's a reason I did not post it as an answer myself.

Comment: Markup in-validation and duplicate ids, do not cause alignment errors...assuming you close all tags, its only css and device specific css(viewport) which is the issue here...

Answer (score -3):

If you mean the whole div (whole page):

`margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;`

Comment: That's what Alex is doing with margin: 0 auto. By defining only two it is saying margin: 0 auto 0 auto;.

Comment: margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; is the exact same thing as margin: 0 auto;

Comment: I find it amazing how many people on SO lately are posting `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` as a fix for various `margin: 0 auto` problems.  **It's the same thing!**

Comment: @cereallarceny its similar but not exactly the same, it does not set the bottom and the top margin