# Webpage starts zoomed in on mobile devices

Tags: html, viewport

I'm using this code on my webpage

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1000, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

I would think the initial scale would make sure the webpage was zoomed out, but it doesn't. Any ideas?

I've tried this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

But, I need the width to be set to 1000px or it doesn't look correct.

### Answer:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1000; user-scalable=0;" />
```

Comment: this solution will solve alignment issues too on smart phones! just wanted to post my findings.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402081/website-left-aligned-on-ipad

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`initial-scale=1.0` tells the browser to set the zoom level to normal (i.e. not zoomed in or out). You only need `width=1000`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1000">
```

Comment: This is really helpful. However you can also try this 
"<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">"

Answer (score 26):

Try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

or

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the user-scalable idea.

Answer (score 10):

In My Case I could successfully stop zooming of the screen by just adding the following code with no extras.

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Comment: This worked for me. I have a simple page with all containers at 100% width. One has a constant 800px by 600px game canvas. I had this for viewport setting. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>` The result was that the page would load zoomed in on mobile, but you could zoom out and it would fit perfect. By removing `initial-scale=1.0` The canvas scaled to fit in the available width and the game did not break.

Comment: WOW. Just removed initial-scale=1.0 ant it works. What the hell...! Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

I also thought that view port was the problem but after testing it I figured viewport was not the problem.

The problem in my case was the CSS: fixed width, or width: 100% instead of width: auto. So if you find that viewport is not the problem - CSS would likely be your next guess.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

The answer is already here in the website that we are using.

If you inspect element the `StackOverflow` and look for the `meta` `viewport` of it. You will see

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

So you are setting the `width` and `height` depends on which is the width, and height of the screen in CSS pixels at a scale of 100%. The `initial-scale` property controls the zoom level when the page is first loaded. And lastly `minimum-scale` is an optional attribute for the viewport, and it defines the minimum zoom that website users are able to do.

Answer (score 4):

None of the answers above worked for me and I managed to figure out the answer.

The initial meta tag was had an initial-scale of 1.

To load the website without zooming in you have to change the initial-scale from 1 to 0.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0, maximum-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried playing with

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1000, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

and it seems my site is indeed rendered  1000px wide at scale 1. However, since my phone's screen has no space for the site, the site continues outside the viewport resulting in the feeling that the site is zoomed in.

Setting this value makes the site 1000px wide zoomed out:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=1000">
```

Is this your issue?

On a side note, 1000px sounds a bit wide for a mobile website, but I assume this website is not originally made for mobile devices?

Answer (score 1):

my problem was becauseI added the body in the css with min-width. It works when I remove it

```
body
{
   padding: 0;
   margin:0;
   min-width: 800px;
   color: black;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Ensure `min-width` is <= than the device's viewport.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=100%">
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using your stylesheet.css with a bootstrap link, make sure is the updated one,
often it gets updated and when it does make cause errors on the old versions.

Comment: Hello! This question already has an accepted answer. Before looking at answered questions, please consider looking at [unanswered ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Unanswered) first. If you do, however, have something to add to an answered question, please consider reading other answers thoroughly first.

Answer (score 0):

I also have had a similar problem in past. This has worked for me every single time.
Try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" initial-scale=1.0 content="width=device-width" />
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at the other answers that were given before. Your approach is mentioned there already. In order to keep the site clear and make it easy to find answers, we try to avoid double answers.

Comment: @ahuemmer This solution is not mentioned here already? It's unique.

Comment: Just a heads up: `meta` elements have `name` and `content` attributes, and `initial-scale=1` belongs inside of the `content` attribute as one of the comma-separated values there – not as an attribute of its own.

Answer (score -1):

I've had a similar problem. Try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1000; initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1"/>
```

I think it has to do with the minimum-scale, but I'm not very sure.

Comment: Hrm... now it won't resize at all, but it's still zoomed in.

Answer (score -2):

Try out this will help you...This worked for me

```
 <meta name="viewport" initial-scale=1.0 content="width=100%">
```