# Webpage opens zoomed on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

When I open my page on mobile, it is automatically zoomed in to probably about 125%. It looks fine when you zoom out, but obviously I want it to open at 100%. I have this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

but was wondering if it's possible that it could be a different issue. My body width and height are currently styled at 100%, but I tried switching to auto and that did not help the zoom effect.

Answer (score 0):

this question has an answer here: [Webpage starts zoomed in on mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272420/webpage-starts-zoomed-in-on-mobile-devices)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1000">
```

Comment: When I try this, it opens the full desktop version on mobile

Comment: Try using % instead of px in your css, fixed it for me.

Comment: You looked the link ? for me '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">' is working very well the mobile version is not zoomed

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem and just adding height to the meta tag solved my issue

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" height="device-height" initial-scale="1" , maximum-scale="1" />
```