# Website when viewed on mobile not center aligned

Tags: html, css, mobile, margin

I'm having issues aligning a website to the center on mobile devices - it is currently left aligned.

The website can be viewed [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140224021756/http://www.justdivinecatering.com.au:80/)<sup>†</sup>.

I have viewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402081/website-left-aligned-on-ipad) question but it has not helped; when `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0" />` the alignment does not change. The margin is set to `0 auto` however the problem remains.

---

<sup>†</sup> The website no longer exists, link changed to Internet Archive but CSS not preserved.

Comment: I believe the float: left property is causing this behaviour

Comment: When i resize ur website on `chrome` . i see 1/4 of the site & rest goes in horizontal scroll.

Comment: I have just removed it from `container` however it's messed up all alignment (if that's what you meant) and not aligned it to the center

Comment: I'd recommend re-doing the unfloated container so it isn't positioned using a -300 margin, if I some time soon I'll work on a fix

Comment: The -300 margin is in place so that the rest of the website isn't pushed under the striped banner. I should however fix that, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a fixed width:

```
#unfloated-container{
    width: 1000px;
}
```

You can use "CSS media query" (try googling for that) to set different size for smaller screens and keep the current size for screens you choose.

You may also need to set different margins (and even more different settings) when the page is viewed in smaller screens!

**EDIT 1:** My comment from an other answer, copied to describe the possibilities for changing floats, width and all other needed settings (styles) for specific screen sizes:

It seems the HTC tries to fit the browser to avoid horizontal scroller. But the problem remain in your CSS, so it seems better to try css media queries (as proposed in my answer) and adjust the style for mobile devices only! This way you can remove floats (float: none), set the width to "width: auto" and adjust margins where needed!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has better fixed your alignment issue but the banner image is still messed up a bit as it was in your original link:

```
#unfloated-container{
margin: -600px auto 0 auto;
padding: 0;
width: 80%;
height: 100%;
}

#container{
margin: 0;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
width: 100%;
}

/*~~~~~ Banner ~~~~~*/
#banner{
margin: 10px 0 0 0;
padding: 0 0 0 130px;
width: 100%;
height: 280px;
float: left;
text-align: center;
}
#banner-image{
margin: 10px 0 0 0;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
width: 100%;
height: 300px;
background-image: url(../images/banner.jpg);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
/*~~~~~~ Links Bar ~~~~~*/
#links{
margin: 300px 0 0 60px;
padding: 7px 0 0 5px;
width: 75%;
height: 100px;
font-size: 20;
}

/*~~~~ Content Area ~~~~*/
#content{
margin: 0px 0 0 0px;
padding: 104px 55px 0 80px;
height: 550px;
width: 865px;
float: left;
overflow: scroll;
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Combining these fixes with @Minister's answer will create the desired result. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set BOTH the viewport width (as you suggested in your question) AND your CSS properties.

To have a mobile responsive website, you need all your css properties to be percentage based. For example, you currently have a css property named `#unfloated-container` set to 1000px. 
That means that your site will always be 1000px wide. Try changing it to 80% instead (or any % you need).

Hope this helps!

Comment: he's not asking for a responsive website he just wants to center align the #container which is currently using float: left

Comment: From what I've seen when simulating a mobile device, I did not see any alignment problem but just that the site was too large for the screen (and not responsive) therefore you can only see the left part of the screen. If I'm mistaken I'll remove my answer.

Comment: I understand, but his question does seem related to the alignment being pushed to the left side as opposed to the responsiveness of the site.

Comment: The website fits on the screen, it however doesn't align to the center of the page

Comment: @jscionti Could you check again if there is horisontal scroller? Could you provide more details how you do the tests (on which device/browser)?

Comment: I am viewing the website from my HTC One/Chrome which doesn't appear to have horizontal scrolls. When I resize my desktop browser I see what you mean - a horizontal scroll appears.

Comment: Unless I'm hallucinating cause it's almost 2am here - on my desktop screen everything is centered. On my mobile screen the site is centered per 1000px (!) meaning it is not 100% of the device width which makes it look like it is aligned left.

Comment: (+1) It seems the HTC tries to fit the browser to avoid horizontal scroller. But the problem remain in your CSS, so it seems better to try css media queries (as proposed in my answer) and adjust the style for mobile devices only! This way you can remove floats (float: none), set the width to "width: auto" and adjust margins where needed!